# What does mean ‘regular function at the origin’?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, definition, regularization

Really I'm new here , and I seek for simple definition about regular function at

the origin when the function is presented as a power series ?

Comment: If the power series consists of powers of $x$. Then it means that the series has a positive radius of convergence. If the series is not centered at the origin (not powers of $x$ but of $x-a$ for some $a\neq0$), then it means that there is an analytic continuation to the origin that is regular at the origin.

Comment: do you meant if is centred in origin and has a positive radius of convergence also it's regular at the origin ?

Comment: Yes, that is what regular means in this context, that the function can be represented by a power series that converges on a neighborhood of the point.

Comment: then also it's taylor series converges near origin and it is aymptotics this what i understand now

Comment: It would improve your Question to cite where you found *regular function* being used.  Normally the author of a textbook or paper would provide the definition or give a reference that supplies the intended meaning.  The tag `regularization` is likely not appropriate here.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of the word *regular* is not precisely defined. Sometimes they say *regular enough* which means (for instance) that a function is differentiable, or twice continuously differentiable and so on. Usually saying this they want the function to fulfill all the needed assumptions.

In your context, if a function is representable as a power series $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$ centered at zero, this series converges in a certain interval. In this interval $f$ is infinitely times differentiable. It is also possible that the power series is convergent only at $x=0$. In this case nothing could be said about $f$ at the other points. Take into account the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^nx^n.$$ It is divergent for any $x\ne 0$ and the function defined by this series is $f\colon\{0\}\to\{a_0\}$, $f(0)=a_0.$ Such function is, of course, not differentiable. It is not possible to compute any limit connected with $f$.